# Solving equations with modified Reverse Polish Notation

Tags: c++, input, postfix-notation

I must write a program with solves equations  with four basic operations. 
The program must look like:

EXAMPLE INPUT:

```
SET a = 1
SET b = 3 
SOLVEFOR c ( 4 * ( b - c + 2) + a ) = ( 2 - a )
```

OUTPUT:

```
c = 5.000000
```

I am using Reverse Polish Notation for evaluating the value of right side of the equation (I know for a fact that there will only be known numbers there). 
As for the left side, that is my problem. I know there must be a way of modifying RPN to get that variable, but I don't have any idea as to how it should be done. Any suggestions?

EDIT: I know this can be done with binary trees, but I'm trying to use RPN.

Comment: How do you use a notation to compute an expression?

Answer (score 0):

If you can solve with binary trees, you can solve with RPN.

First draw your solution with binary trees on the paper. It is easier to think when you can see. You will make rebalancing operations on the tree without affecting the equation result.

Once the unknown isolated in the left-hand-side, you are done. Each rebalancing operation has an equivalent operation in RPN (which is a flat representation of a tree).

When you see your drawn solution, the insight will come.